# src of image doesn't change when user uploads image again (socket.io)

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I'm using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socketio-file-upload) module to upload images via socket.io.
Here's the client side code:

```
<img src="/img/avatar-2-128.png" alt="" id="signinbox_photo"> //avatar-2-128.png is an avatar that will be replaced
<input type="file" id="siofu_input" />


//upload the image to the server
var uploader = new SocketIOFileUpload(socket);
uploader.listenOnInput(document.getElementById("siofu_input"));

socket.on('update photo', function(data){ //update the src attr of the img tag
    var signinbox_photo = $('#signinbox_photo');
    signinbox_photo.attr("src",`/img/user_images/${data.id}.jpg`);
});
```

Server side:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var siofu = require("socketio-file-upload");

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var uploader = new siofu();
    var dir = "./public/img/user_images/"
    uploader.dir = dir;
    uploader.listen(socket); //save the file

    uploader.on("saved", function(event){
        fs.rename(dir + event.file.name, dir + socket.id + ".jpg", function(err) { //replace the file name to socket id
            if ( err ) console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
        });
        io.sockets.emit('update photo', {id: socket.id}) //emit to client so it updates the src of the image
    });

});
```

When the user uploads a picture, it works and everything is as expected, but when the user uploads again, it replaces the file in the server but doesn't update the src of the image in the client. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The URL you're passing to the src attribute is within back ticks. ```. That is used to pass a "litteral" string. Try with single quotes `'`, since you have a variable to interpret inside it...

Comment: Do you just mean `data` and not `data.id`. It looks like you pass the `id` from `socket.id`, but I don't know much about socket.io

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette It's the same, I tried your way and it didn't work

Comment: @Jimenemex data is an object that has the passed id in it from emit

Comment: Ok.. Then try `console.log("/img/user_images/${data.id}.jpg");` to see if it's a correct source...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette It is absolutely correct, it does update the src, as I said, it only fails to update the src when the user tries to upload again

Comment: Try dropping the `<img>` tag and just re-create it?

Comment: @Jimenemex I just tried it, it's still not changing... As long as the src is the same, it just doesn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because everytime you upload image, the image name is same and there is no way for browser to not know that you have uploaded different image with same name. There is workaround though. You can add random number as query parameter while assigning the src in client side like this :

```
//upload the image to the server
var uploader = new SocketIOFileUpload(socket);
uploader.listenOnInput(document.getElementById("siofu_input"));

socket.on('update photo', function(data){ //update the src attr of the img tag
    var signinbox_photo = $('#signinbox_photo');
    signinbox_photo.attr("src",`/img/user_images/${data.id}.jpg?r=${Math.random()}`);
});
```

Comment: Yes, I thought of it this way, but the problem is, I will use the socket.id to render the image when the user "signs in" (temporary sign in)

Comment: You can use the socket.id to render the image, the random number is there just to make sure that browser will re-request image after upload.